# NEG Google Cloud similarity in Azure Cloud paired with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-cloud-services, azure-aks

Right now, my production is using [Google Cloud Network Endpoint Group](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs)
I am planning to use Multi-cluster spread into different Cloud Provider.

In Google Cloud, the flow is like `visitor -> LB -> NEG -> Pod`

I am curious, what is NEG called in Azure Cloud ? After reading azure docs, i don't find the similarity of NEG. Only [Static IP Address LB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip) and [Standard IP Address LB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard)

In google cloud, the best practice is Network Endpoint Group. What is the best practice in Azure Cloud ?

Comment: I cannot understand the NEG clearly. Can you explain what does it do? Is it the same as the backend pool of the Load Balancer?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes, the answer OP is looking for is [backend pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/backend-pool-management)

Comment: @CharlesXu Can we connect Backend Pool of Load Balancer Azure to Azure Kubernetes Service ? NEG is Network Endpoint Group which is grouping pods into a group and then received traffic from LoadBalancer

Comment: Actually, Azure managed the load balancer of the AKS, you only need to create the service, then Azure create the rules to make the service accessible outside.

Comment: Do you solve this question? If not, what's else you need? If yes, you can add an answer to display the solution or delete it.

Comment: Are you azure expert? Do you have small group to discuss about aks-lb azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to consider this method below to replace Google Cloud Load Balancer NEG, https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/

or this one for fastest deployment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing